# jacoco including apache in report

Tags: maven, junit, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

i am first time trying jacoco for coverage :
but jacoco reports also include apache dependecies it it. 
[image]

here is my pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*org/apache/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

i tried

```
<exclude>**/lib/*</exclude>
```

also. nothing is removing this apache coverage from report.

below is project structure.

[image]

Comment: can you please share your project structure?

Comment: i got the solution . <exclude>**/axis-1.4.jar/**</exclude> this worked for me to exclude external jar file

Answer (score 0):

for my code below exclude worked

```
<exclude>**/axis-1.4.jar/**</exclude>
```